# Parse Command Line giving errors on only one computer

Tags: parse-platform

I am receiving errors when using Parse Command Line on my iMac. It works fine on my MacBook, so the services are available and working fine. I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall the command line as well as restart my computer. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. (This is happening with all commands, not just 'parse list')

```
Stevens-iMac:bin stevenhayes$ parse list
Please login to Parse using your email and password.
Email: -- my email is here --   
Password (will be hidden): 
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x564c]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.(*apps).restFetchApps(0x106526b0, 0x1068e440, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/apps.go:94 +0x1cc
main.(*login).authUser(0x10652690, 0x1068e440, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/login.go:63 +0xd9
main.(*apps).authUser(0x10652690, 0x1068e440, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/apps.go:104 +0xee
main.(*listCmd).run(0x4d9cec, 0x1068e440, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/list_cmd.go:33 +0x5e
main.*listCmd.(main.run)·fm(0x1068e440, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/list_cmd.go:47 +0x39
main.func·011(0x10649680, 0x4d9cec, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/main.go:163 +0x127
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x10649680, 0x4d9cec, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:399 +0x29b
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).findAndExecute(0x10648fa0, 0x10662430, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:366 +0x9b
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0x10648fa0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:452 +0x834
main.main()
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/main.go:408 +0x90c

goroutine 5 [syscall, 1 minutes]:
os/signal.loop()
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:21 +0x1b
created by os/signal.init·1
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:27 +0x2e

goroutine 6 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
main.func·017()
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/main.go:341 +0x33
created by main.main
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/main.go:343 +0x136

goroutine 15 [chan receive]:
net.goLookupIP(0x106f4400, 0xd, 0x1068a8a0, 0x8, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go:392 +0x39f
net.lookupIP(0x106f4400, 0xd, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:66 +0x7f
net.func·026(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/lookup.go:79 +0x44
net.(*singleflight).doCall(0x4d31a0, 0x1068ec80, 0x106f4400, 0xd, 0x106626c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/singleflight.go:91 +0x1e
created by net.(*singleflight).DoChan
    /usr/local/go/src/net/singleflight.go:84 +0x314

goroutine 17 [IO wait]:
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0x1069a678, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0x3c
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0x1069a678, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:89 +0x3a
net.(*netFD).Read(0x1069a640, 0x106d7800, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x3065bd20, 0x10653b78)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:242 +0x2ea
net.(*conn).Read(0x10662770, 0x106d7800, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:121 +0xb4
net.(*UDPConn).readDNSResponse(0x10662770, 0x1069a600, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go:43 +0x8c
net.exchange(0x106f5660, 0x11, 0x106f5320, 0x17, 0x106f001c, 0x2a05f200, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go:146 +0x412
net.tryOneName(0x10682570, 0x106f5320, 0x17, 0x1c, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go:175 +0x39d
net.lookup(0x106f4400, 0xd, 0x1c, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3065d068, 0x106f52e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go:311 +0x379
net.func·020(0x1065001c)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go:386 +0x35
created by net.goLookupIP
    /usr/local/go/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go:388 +0x330

goroutine 12 [select]:
net.func·019()
    /usr/local/go/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go:241 +0x2af
created by net.loadConfig
    /usr/local/go/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go:269 +0x1a4
```

Comment: even when I did 'parse version', it took over 20 seconds to come back with 2.1.3

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue myself. Not quite sure what happened, but to fix it, I went into my network settings on my mac, deleted the Wi-Fi configuration, and then added a new Wi-Fi configuration. Once I was reconnected to the internet, the issue was resolved. Hope this will help anyone else having these same issues.